# Android HttpPost error java.net UnknownHostException

Tags: android, http, iis

I have a java application trying to post to a php file on an IIS server and when I execute the post I get the java.net UnknownHostException. I have the  set in the androidmanifet.xml right above the application element. Can somebody please help?

Comment: have you tried inserting a breakpoint and turning on the debugger?

Comment: Whats the Hostname you are using? Is the host something on a local subnet or ip? Is the destination routable? What is the phone on, cell wifi etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out the emulator that was started through eclipse would not connect to the internet. Had to manually start it up. Does anyone know why the emulator through eclipse does not connect to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If your server is on a subnet, make sure you're including the full hostname in your `HttpPost`, e.g. `barney.awesome.domain.com` and not simply `barney`

Comment: I do have the full hostname included